# Multilingual Panels does not allow content translation

Tags: panels, i18n-l10n, 7

Drupal 7.26
Multilingual Panels  7.x-1.0
Panels  7.x-3.4
Domain Access   7.x-3.11
Domain + I18n Variables Integration   7.x-1.0

Hello, I am attempting to use Multilingual Panels to translate panel content.
I followed the instructions given by the Multilingual Panels module owner, but when
I try and translate panel content I get an error in the "Configure Content" section:

"You can translate settings for different languages, but you must set Multilingual Standard as display renderer in order to see result."

Here is the error when I view content on a page. Note the "Default", "English", "Spanish".
[image]

If I click on "English" or "Spanish", I get this error:
[image]

I did set the Multilingual renderer for this particular Page.
[image]

If you go to Panels-->Settings you can set the default renderer. It has been set.
[image]

Oh, I also have both english and spanish hooked up through configuration-->regional and language->language.  I am also translating non panel content as a confirmation that spanish and english are set up.

Anyone know why it would be doing this?

Thanks,

David